# Namespace's vairable scope in Tcl with procedures

Tags: namespaces, tcl, scope

In Tcl, I am trying to work on namespaces and I came across the following question.

My code is as below.

```
% namespace eval counter {
    #Declaring the variable 'num' in counter namespace
    variable num 0 
    proc next { } { 
        #Accessing 'num' here, since we have already declared it in it's namespace
        return [ incr num ] 
    }
    proc reset { } { 
        #Same as above
        return [ set num 0 ] 
    }
}
%########OUTPUT############ 
% ::counter::next
1
% ::counter::next
1
% ::counter::reset
0
% ::counter::next
1
```

As you can see, I am able to access the value 'num' without any issues. But, value 'num' retained it's value for each call.

By declaring the variable 'num' inside each procedures, the value retained.

```
% namespace eval counter {
    variable num 0 
    proc next { } { 
        variable num
        return [ incr num ] 
    }
    proc reset { } { 
        variable num
        return [ set num 0 ] 
    }
}
% ######OUTPUT#########
% ::counter::next
1
% ::counter::next
2
% ::counter::next
3
% ::counter::reset
0
```

Why this behaves in this way ?

What is the significance of declaring the variables inside procedures too ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a language design choice. Tcl uses dynamic rather than lexical scope, so names aren't automatically imported everywhere even if `proc` definitions are lexically parts of a `namespace eval` body. It's the same thing with global names, which aren't imported into a `proc` definition unless you use `global`. Note that this goes both ways: if you happen to make changes to a variable with the same name as a namespace or global variable, your changes won't leak out unless you want them to (remember that Tcl uses implicit declaration of variables: `set` will create a new variable only if the name isn't used already).

It can be a bother to remember to put in `variable` commands in every procedure that needs them, and it's easy to get obscure bugs when you forget, but on the whole it's a sound design choice, I think.

Documentation: [global](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/global.htm), [namespace](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/namespace.htm), [proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [variable](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/variable.htm)